# Reading file with Apache Arrow ArrowFileReader in .net

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-5, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I am trying to read the content of an arrow file but I was not able to find the functions to get the actual data from it. I am not able to find any useful example to read the data too. For example [here](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/csharp/README.md).

The code example for writing and reading in C#:

```
// Write
var recordBatch = new Apache.Arrow.RecordBatch.Builder(memoryAllocator)
    .Append("Column A", false, col => col.Int32(array => array.AppendRange(Enumerable.Range(5, 15))))
    .Build();

using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(filePath))
using (var writer = new Apache.Arrow.Ipc.ArrowFileWriter(stream, recordBatch.Schema, true))
{
    await writer.WriteRecordBatchAsync(recordBatch);
    await writer.WriteEndAsync();
}

// Read
var reader = Apache.Arrow.Ipc.ArrowFileReader.FromFile(filePath);
var readBatch = await reader.ReadNextRecordBatchAsync();
var col = readBatch.Column(0);
```

By debugging the code, I can see the values in the col Values property but I have no way of accessing this information in the code.
[image]
Am I missing anything or is there a different approach to read the data?

Comment: Gosh I am with you. This has been the most frustrating thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Apache.Arrow` package does not do any compute today.  It will read in the file and you will have access to the raw buffers of data.  This is sufficient for a number of intermediary tasks (e.g. services that shuttle data to and from or aggregate data files).  So if you want to do a lot of operations on the data you may want some kind of dataframe library.

One such library is the [`Microsoft.Data.Analysis`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Analysis/) library which has added a `DataFrame` type which [can be created from an Arrow RecordBatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.analysis.dataframe.fromarrowrecordbatch?view=ml-dotnet-preview#Microsoft_Data_Analysis_DataFrame_FromArrowRecordBatch_Apache_Arrow_RecordBatch_).  There is some explanation and examples of the library in this [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-dataframe/).

I haven't worked with that library much but I was able to put together a short example of reading an Arrow file and printing the data:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Apache.Arrow.Ipc;
using Microsoft.Data.Analysis;

namespace DataframeExperiment
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task AsyncMain()
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead("/tmp/test.arrow"))
            using (var reader = new ArrowFileReader(stream))
            {
                var recordBatch = await reader.ReadNextRecordBatchAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("Read record batch with {0} column(s)", recordBatch.ColumnCount);
                var dataframe = DataFrame.FromArrowRecordBatch(recordBatch);

                var columnX = dataframe["x"];
                foreach (var value in columnX)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(value);
                }
            }
        }
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AsyncMain().Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

I created the test file with a small python script:

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.ipc as ipc

tab = pa.Table.from_pydict({'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': ['x', 'y', 'z']})
with ipc.RecordBatchFileWriter('/tmp/test.arrow', schema=tab.schema) as writer:
    writer.write_table(tab)
```

You could presumably also create the test file using C# with `Apache.Arrow`'s [array builders](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/csharp/examples/FluentBuilderExample/Program.cs).

#### Update (Using `Apache.Arrow` directly)

On the other hand, if you want to use `Apache.Arrow` directly, and still get access to the data, then you can use typed arrays (e.g. Int32Array, Int64Array).  You will first need to determine the type of your array somehow (either through prior knowledge of the schema or `as` / `is` style checks or pattern matching).

Here is an example using `Apache.Arrow` alone:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Apache.Arrow;
using Apache.Arrow.Ipc;

namespace ArrayValuesExperiment
{
    class Program
    {

        static async Task AsyncMain()
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead("/tmp/test.arrow"))
            using (var reader = new ArrowFileReader(stream))
            {
                var recordBatch = await reader.ReadNextRecordBatchAsync();
                // Here I am relying on the fact that I know column
                // 0 is an int64 array.
                var columnX = (Int64Array) recordBatch.Column(0);
                for (int i = 0; i < columnX.Values.Length; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(columnX.Values[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AsyncMain().Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The reader.ReadNextRecordBatchAsync() method is returning a null value. I see that the Arrow file has the data and the reader has the schema field populated. Any idea what might be happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the second approach proposed by Pace, an utility function like below can be used to get the values

```
        private static dynamic GetArrayData(IArrowArray array)
    {
        return array switch
        {
            Int32Array int32array =>int32array.Values.ToArray(),
            Int16Array int16array => int16array.Values.ToArray(),
            StringArray stringArray => stringArray.Values.ToArray(),
            FloatArray floatArray => floatArray.Values.ToArray(),
            Int64Array int64Array => int64Array.Values.ToArray(),
            DoubleArray doubleArray => doubleArray.Values.ToArray(),
            Time32Array time32Array => time32Array.Values.ToArray(),
            Time64Array time64Array => time64Array.Values.ToArray(),
            BooleanArray booleanArray => booleanArray.Values.ToArray(),
            Date32Array date32Array => date32Array.Values.ToArray(),
            Date64Array date64Array => date64Array.Values.ToArray(),
            Int8Array int8Array => int8Array.Values.ToArray(),
            UInt16Array uint6Array => uint6Array.Values.ToArray(),
            UInt8Array uInt8Array => uInt8Array.Values.ToArray(),
            UInt64Array uInt64Array => uInt64Array.Values.ToArray(),
            _ => throw new NotImplementedException(),
        };
    }
```

then iterate over the recordBatch as

```
          object[,] results = new Object[recordBatch.Length, recordBatch.ColumnCount];
            var col = 0;
            foreach (var array in recordBatch.Arrays)
            {
                var row = 0;                                     
                foreach (var data in GetArrayData(array))
                {
                    results[row++, col] = data;
                }
                col++;

            }

            return results;
```

Worth noting however that StringArrays return Bytes so you need to convert to back to string for example using

```
System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(stringArray.Values)
```